# Ошибка подключения к базе (No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Подключаюсь к базе MySQL на другом сервере через интернет.

При запуске в Intellij IDEA (IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2
Build #IC-145.972, built on May 14, 2016) все прекрасно - ошибок нет.
Но, при запуске скомпилированного jar появляется ошибка подключения к базе:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/BaseName
```

Предполагаю, что в исполняемый файл не включена библиотека.

Но в свойствах проекта в "Global librires" указана "mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.39".

При добавлении в "Librires" "Project setting" из Maven сообщает о неиспользуемой библиотеке и предлагает удалить.

Как сделать так, чтобы собранный jar видел драйвер для jdbc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить в файл проекта: `ИмяПроекта/.idea/artefacts/Имяпроекта_jar.xml`

строку:

```
<element id="extracted-dir" path="$PROJECT_DIR$/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar" path-in-jar="/" />
```

Соответственно, в папке `lib` файл `mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar` должен присутствовать.